# How to make a sorted list of multiples for several numbers?

Tags: list, haskell

I'm having trouble with an assignment from my Haskell class. I have already solved a partial problem of this task: I have to write a function that takes an Int and creates an infinite list with the multiples of that Int.

```
function :: Int -> [Int]
function d = [d*x | x <- [1..]]
```

**Console:**

```
ghci> take 10 (function 3)
```

gives

```
[3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27,30]
```

In the second task I have to extend the function so that it accepts a list of numbers and uses each value of that list as a factor (d previously). For example:

```
ghci> take 10 (function [3, 5])
```

should give

```
[3,5,6,9,10,12,15,18,20,21]
```

Already tried a list comprehension like

```
function d = [y*x | y <- [1..], x <- d]
```

but the function returns the list in an unsorted form:

```
[3,5,6,10,9,15,12,20,15,25]
```

We got the tip that we should use the modulo function of Haskell, but I have no real idea how to proceed exactly. Do you have a good tip for me?

Comment: Try using `filter` together with the modulo function

Comment: What is "unwanted form" mean ?

Comment: @talex My current solution gives:

    ghci> take 10 (function [3,5]) --->
    [3,5,6,10,9,15,12,20,15,25]

    (1*3, 1*5, 2*3, 2*5, 3*3, 3*5, 4*3, 4*5, 5*3, 5*5),

but it should be sorted ascending like

    [3,5,6,9,10,12,15,18,20,21]

    (1*3, 1*5, 2*3, 3*3, 2*5, 4*3, 3*5, 5*3, 4*5, 6*3)

Comment: Instead of starting with nothing and adding "correct" numbers, try starting with all numbers and removing "wrong" numbers.

Comment: `[d*x | x <- [1..]]` could be simplified to `[d, d+d ..]`.

Comment: `map (d*) [1..]` is arguably more idiomatic (or at least I would say it is, but I'm new to the language so my stylistic judgement could be off)

Comment: @RobinZigmond It's less efficient: For each new element you have to multiply `x` up from scratch, whereas my solution just has to add `x` to the previous result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a one liner.

```
import Data.List (nub)

f xs = nub [x|x<-[1..], d<-xs, x `mod` d == 0]

take 10 $ f [3,5] -- [3,5,6,9,10,12,15,18,20,21]
```

runtime should be O(n² + n*d) from the resulting list. The *nub* runs in O(n²). Would be nice to get rid of it.

```
g xs = [x |x<-[1..], let ys = map (mod x) xs in 0 `elem` ys]
```

This performs pretty ok. It should run in O (n*d). I also have this version which I thought performs at least as well as *g*, but apparently it performs better than *f* and worse than *g*.

```
h xs = [x |x<-[1..], or [x `mod` d == 0 |d<-xs] ]
```

I am not sure why that is, *or* is lazy as far as I can tell and I don`t see any reason why it should run slower. It especially does not scale as well when you increase the length of the input list.

```
i xs = foldr1 combine [[x, x+x ..] |x<- sort xs]
    where
      combine l [] = l
      combine [] r = r
      combine l@(x:xs) r@(y:ys)
        | x < y = (x: combine xs r)
        | x > y = (y: combine l ys)
        | otherwise = (x: combine xs ys)
```

Not a one liner anymore, but the fastest I could come up with. I am not a hundred percent sure why it makes such a big difference on runtime if you right or left fold and if you sort the input list in advance. But it should not make a difference on the result since:

```
commutative a b = combine [a] [b] == combine [b] [a]
```

I find it completely insane to think about this Problem in terms of folding a recursive function over a list of endless lists of multiples of input coefficients.

On my System it is still about a factor of 10 slower than another solution presented here using Data.List.Ordered.

Comment: You can think about this problem as "I have a bunch of increasing streams and I have to create one single increasing stream out of them". The way I think about this is "Let me define an accumulator `acc` and a function `f` that decide at each step which element from all streams goes into the accumulator". `f` should be recursive, since at each step you are doing the same. From this point of view, `foldr` over a recursive function looks as the perfect candidate. Just sharing my thoughts

Comment: @steve `combine` = `Data.List.Ordered.union`. :) recursive or not, it just combines two streams into one. you meant good "insane", like thrilling, right? as for speed differences, you only hint at, not describe, but they make sense. see discussion of "left-leaning" vs "right-leaning" (and tree-like) folding on https://wiki.haskell.org/Prime_numbers. but only if you use more than 2 divisors; if there are 2 there shouldn't be any difference, as there's no deepening structure.

Comment: you're folding it over a list of only 2 lists btw (if `xs == [2,3]`) (each *is* infinite of course). but it's possible to fold over n infinite list as well. examples at the aforementioned page, and in Data.List.Ordered. with it we can even call `O.unionAll [[n,n+n..] | n <-[1..]]`. --- the 10x factor is because package functions are compiled.

Comment: The factor of 10 really is because it was not compiled. Compiling it gives a neck and neck race. @WillNess of course I mean the good "insane"

Comment: right. :) neck and neck because it is the same thing, essentially. you can see it in the source code.

Comment: well, not exactly. I am benchmarking against `j xs = foldr O.union [] [ [x, x+x ..] | x <- xs ]` and folding O.union is still faster than my combine function.

Comment: but yes, you are absolutely right. It's basically the same.

Answer (score 3):

If you think of `d` being a factor not as

```
y = x * d
```

but instead

```
y `mod` d == 0,
```

then you can source the list comprehension from the list `[1..]` and add a predicate function, for example:

```
function ds 
    | null ds   = [1..]
    | otherwise = [ x | x <- [1..], qualifies x ]
    where
      qualifies x = any (==0) $ (flip mod) <$> ds <*> [x]
```

A more expressive version which is perhaps easier to grasp in the beginning:

```
function' ds   
    | null ds   = [1..]
    | otherwise = [ x | x <- [1..], divByAnyIn ds x ]
    where
      divByAnyIn ds x = 
          case ds of
            (d:ds') -> if x `mod` d == 0 then True 
                                         else divByAnyIn ds' x
            _       -> False
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it with the modulo function, you can define a simple one-liner

```
foo ds = filter (\x -> any (== 0) [mod x d | d <- ds]) [1..]
```

or, in the more readable form,

```
foo ds = filter p [1..]
  where
  p x = any id [ mod x d == 0 | d <- ds]
      = any (== 0) [ mod x d | d <- ds]
      = not $ null [ () | d <- ds, mod x d == 0]
      = null [ () | d <- ds, mod x d /= 0]
      = null [ () | d <- ds, rem x d > 0]
```

With this, we get

```
> take 20 $ foo [3,5]
[3,5,6,9,10,12,15,18,20,21,24,25,27,30,33,35,36,39,40,42]
```

But, it is inefficient: `last $ take 20 $ foo [300,500] == 4200`, so to produce those 20 numbers this code tests 4200. And it gets worse the bigger the numbers are.

We should produce `n` numbers in time roughly proportional to `n`, instead.

For this, first write each number's multiples in their own list:

```
[ [d*x | x <- [1..]] | d <- ds ] ==
[ [d, d+d ..] | d <- ds ]
```

Then, *merge* these ordered increasing lists of numbers in an ordered fashion to produce one ordered non-decreasing list of numbers. The package [`data-ordlist`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-ordlist) has many [functions](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-ordlist-0.4.7.0/docs/Data-List-Ordered.html#g:3) to deal with this kind of lists:

```
import qualified Data.List.Ordered as O
import           Data.List               (sort)

bar :: (Ord a, Num a, Enum a) => [a] -> [a]
bar ds = foldr    O.merge [] [ [d, d+d ..] | d <- ds ]
       = O.foldt' O.merge [] [ [d, d+d ..] | d <- ds ]   -- more efficient, 
       = O.mergeAll [ [d, d+d ..] | d <- sort ds ]       -- tree-shaped folding
```

If we want the produced list to not contain any duplicates, i.e. create an increasing list, we can change it to

```
baz ds = O.nub $ foldr O.merge [] [ [d, d+d ..] | d <- ds ]
       = foldr    O.union [] [ [d, d+d ..] | d <- ds ]
       = O.foldt' O.union [] [ [d, d+d ..] | d <- ds ]
       = O.unionAll [ [d, d+d ..] | d <- sort ds ]
       = (O.unionAll . map (iterate =<< (+)) . sort)  ds
```

Oh, and, unlike the quadratic `Data.List.nub`, `Data.List.Ordered.nub` is linear, spends `O(1)` time on each element of the input list.

Answer (score 1):

The answer here just shows the idea, it is not a optimized solution, there may exists many way to implement it.

Firstly, calculate all the value of each factors from the inputted list:

```
map (\d->[d*x|x<-[1..]]) xs
```

For example: `xs = [3, 5]` gives

```
[[3, 6, 9, ...], [5, 10, 15, ...]]
```

then, find the minimum value of 1st element of each list as:

```
findMinValueIndex::[(Int, [Int])]->Int
findMinValueIndex xss = minimum $ 
                        map fst $ 
                        filter (\p-> (head $ snd p) == minValue) xss
    where minValue = minimum $ map (head . snd) xss
```

Once we found the list hold the minimum value, return it and remove the minimum value from list as:

```
sortMulti xss = 
            let idx = findMinValueIndex $ zip [0..] xss
            in  head (xss!!idx):sortMulti (updateList idx (tail $ xss!!idx) xss
```

So, for example, after find the first value (i.e. `3`) of the result, the lists for find next value is:

```
[[6, 9, ...], [5, 10, 15, ...]]
```

repeat above steps we can construct the desired list. Finally, remove the duplicated values. Here is the completed coding:

```
import Data.Sequence (update, fromList)
import Data.Foldable (toList)

function :: [Int] -> [Int]
function xs = removeDup $ sortMulti $ map (\d->[d*x|x<-[1..]]) xs
    where sortMulti xss = 
            let idx = findMinValueIndex $ zip [0..] xss
            in  head (xss!!idx):sortMulti (updateList idx (tail $ xss!!idx) xss)

removeDup::[Int]->[Int]
removeDup [] = []
removeDup [a] = [a]
removeDup (x:xs) | x == head xs = removeDup xs
                 | otherwise = x:removeDup xs

findMinValueIndex::[(Int, [Int])]->Int
findMinValueIndex xss = minimum $ 
                        map fst $ 
                        filter (\p-> (head $ snd p) == minValue) xss
    where minValue = minimum $ map (head . snd) xss

updateList::Int->[Int]->[[Int]]->[[Int]]
updateList n xs xss = toList $ update n xs $ fromList xss
```

Comment: BTW I tried to simplify your function and ended up with `function = O.nub . unfoldr g . map (iterate =<< (+))
      where {
      g mss = Just (m, s:r)
                where {
                ((m:s):r) = sortBy (comparing head) mss }}`, 
which does seem like a nice encoding of `O.mergeAll` in  basic functions :) 
under the assumption that the input list is *short* 
(and contains only infinite lists, of course), so `sort` time isn't an issue. `O.` is short for `Data.List.Ordered` from `data-ordlist` package. :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a pretty nice recursive solution

```
function' :: Int -> [Int]
function' d = [d * x | x <- [1..]]

braid :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
braid []        bs = bs
braid as        [] = as
braid aa@(a:as) bb@(b:bs) 
  | a < b     = a:braid as bb
  | a == b    = a:braid as bs # avoid duplicates
  | otherwise = b:braid aa bs

function :: [Int] -> [Int]
function ds = foldr braid [] (map function' ds)
```

`braid` function builds the desired list "on the fly" using only input's head and laziness