# Haskell, how to calculate divider from an infinite list?

Tags: haskell

How can I write a function which receives a list, for example `[7, 8, 9]`.

The function has inside an infinite list. It will calculate all divisors from an infinite list.

For example `take 5 (f [7, 8, 9])` output will be `[7, 8, 9, 14, 16]`

Second example `take 7 (f [7, 8, 9])`  output will be `[7, 8, 9, 14, 16, 18, 21]`

I hope you can understand what I mean.

My code looks like this:

```
myFunction list = [x | x <- [1..], el <-[list], x `mod` el == 0]
```

My code works only with constant list. If I write

```
myFunction list = [x | x <- [1..], el <-[7, 8], x `mod` el == 0]
```

It works only for 7 and 8

How can I pass an arbitrary list?

Comment: `[list]` is a single-element list (the one element being `list`). Did you mean `el <- list`?

Comment: Your logic looks suspect to me. What's the expected result of `take 10 (myFunction [2, 3])`?

Comment: @melpomene (take 10 (myFunction [2, 3]) output will be [2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 15] all first 10 numbers from infinity numbers which we can divide without remainder. yes it is multiplies

Comment: Well, your function actually returns `[2,3,4,6,6,8,9,10,12,12]`. [Live demo](https://tio.run/##TYxLCoAgAAX3neItCyyytrntEiIoJSR@ijIo6O6Wu5Yzw3uLOqx2LiV/j2eYolkDnDkiGPiFBxeGGpw2jSDQLkOu5PPSr7PMjjG0oii8MuFbbbsJEWVUVoO2KH@/vCPoRVWl9AI).

Comment: You are correct. this output is not correct. I want output without duplicate. How can filter this list from duplicate?

Comment: Instead of binding `list` you could try ``any (\el -> x `mod` el == 0) list``

Comment: Alternatively you could use `nub` from `Data.List` to remove duplicates but it's unnecessarily inefficient to do it that way

Comment: @luqui It works perfectly thanks. But I don't understand, how any function in this case works?

Comment: may be duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54107722/how-to-make-a-sorted-list-of-multiples-for-several-numbers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a sorted list of multiples for several numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54107722/how-to-make-a-sorted-list-of-multiples-for-several-numbers)

Comment: See also [New state of the art in unlimited generation of Hamming sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12480291/791604), which *starts* from the solution listed as an answer here and improves from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First let’s solve the case for a single item instead of a list:

```
multiples n | n > 0 = [n * i | i <- [1..]]
```

That was easy enough. Now suppose we have `multiples 2` and `multiples 3`, how can we compute `multiples [2,3]`, i.e. the increasing sequence of numbers made of the multiples of 2 or 3, or in other words, the increasing list of numbers made that are either in the increasing list of numbers `multiples 2` or `multiples 3`? Try this:

```
merge (x:xs) (y:ys) = case compare x y of
  GT -> y : merge (x:xs) ys
  LT -> x : merge xs (y:ys)
  EQ -> x : merge xs ys
```

So now we can implement the desired function:

```
f (x:xs) = foldr merge (multiples x) (multiples <$> xs)
```

Comment: or use `foldr1`.